# Error using itertext() in python 2.7.3

Tags: python-2.7

When I run the code below, I get a message saying `AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'itertext'`

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
url = '[filenamehere].xml'
tree = ET.ElementTree(file=url)
for elem in tree.itertext():
    print repr(elem)
```

It works with just `tree.iter()`  I'm using Python 2.7.3 in Linux Mint Maya.  According to the Python documentation, `itertext()` was added in 2.7, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Groan time... `itertext` was added to `Element`, not `ElementTree`. Try `tree.getroot().itertext()`.

Comment: @tdelaney got it right, for more info, see: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#l498